# PubSub message against a Python Cloud Run not being acknowledged

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a PubSub topic that triggers a python Cloud Run. The topic is defined in terraform as the following:

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "api" {
  name  = "api-v-4-sub"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.elementary_api_trigger.name

  ack_deadline_seconds = 60

  push_config {
    push_endpoint = google_cloud_run_service.dbt.status[0].url
    oidc_token {
      service_account_email = google_service_account.dbt_invoker.email
    }
  }

  dead_letter_policy {
    dead_letter_topic     = google_pubsub_topic.api_trigger_dead_letter.id
    max_delivery_attempts = 5
  }

}
```

However, the message seems to not been acknowledged as it is being retried all the time, even though in the logs I see that the function has been executed and a 204 code has been returned. Neither do it gets as a fail, and even I have a log of the delivery attempt number 176, which shouldn't be there because its limited to 5 attempts. The logs:

```
2023-06-13 18:32:46.021 | INFO | api:process_pubsub_message:71 - Got message {'deliveryAttempt': 4, 'message': {'data': 'ZWRyX21vbml0b3Iuc2VsZWN0IHRhZzplY3NjLHBvc3Qtb3JkZXI=', 'messageId': '8380650465410090', 'message_id': '8380650465410090', 'publishTime': '2023-06-13T18:29:43.482Z', 'publish_time': '2023-06-13T18:29:43.482Z'}, 'subscription': 'projects/project/subscriptions/api-v-4-sub'}
2023-06-13 18:29:51.582 | INFO | data_warehouse:run_command:32 - dbt test --select tag:tag
INFO: ip:16076 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
```

The code of the Cloud Run is the following:

```
@app.post("/")
async def process_pubsub_message(
    request: Request,
    publisher: PublisherClient = Depends(get_publisher),
    settings: Settings = Depends(get_settings),
):
    request_data = await request.json()
    data = request_data["message"]["data"]
    message_data = parse_pubsub_data(data)
    logger.info(f"Got message {request_data}")

    run_response = test_f(message_data)

    return run_response

def test_f(message_data):
    output = subprocess.run_command(["monitor"])
    if output.result.stderr:
        return JSONResponse(content=f"Bad request {output.result.stderr}", status_code=400)
    else:
        return Response(status_code=204)
```

However, I also tried with the example in https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#looking_at_the_code, so my function was like:

```
def test_f(message_data):
    output = subprocess.run_command(["monitor"])
    if output.result.stderr:
        return f"Bad request {output.result.stderr}", 400
    else:
        return "", 204
```

The `test_f` function is being executed, not only because of the logs but also because it's a process that interacts with an external service, and that service gets the interaction correctly. I have absolutely no idea what is going on. Could anyone help me fixing this, please? Thanks!

Comment: Can you see how long the whole request takes? You set the ack dealine to 60 seconds. If your request takes longer, you cannot acknowledge in time and pubsub does not even see your 204.

Comment: It was exactly that, thank you very much! Is there a way though, to prevent pubsub to retry indefinitely if the message takes longer than the ack deadline?

Comment: I added ,y comment as an answer, please accept it so that others can see the issue is resolved. You set the delivery attempts to 5, so PubSub should try only five times. Are you sure that you configured dead lettering correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the maximum ack deadline to 60 seconds.
If your request takes longer, PubSub will not see the 204 answer and retry again.

So you could increase your ack deadline.

About the indefinitely retry: check if you configured dead lettering correct. You can see if it is configured correctly if you go to the subscription in the cloud console and then to "Dead Lettering":
[image]